# Trocar ícone do APP em Tempo de Execução IOS

Tags: swift, ícone

É possível alterar o ícone do app em tempo de execução. Pois tenho um APP que vai ser usado por diversos clientes, gostaria de alterar o nome do APP e o ícone quando o cliente fazer login. Estou utilizando Swift 2.0 atualmente.
Grato desde já.

Comment: Só se for para OSX ou App próprio da apple. iOS o máximo que você pode fazer é adicionar um texto no badge do icone

Comment: O que você pode fazer é dentro do aplicativo, home e talz, páginas...
Se não um app para cada cliente.

Comment: É o que eu temia, vou ter que acabar lançando uma versão para cada cliente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programaticamente você não pode fazer isso!
Você pode automatizar seu Build utilizando o FastLane e escrevendo um script para você publicar para cada cliente automaticamente.
Dá uma olhada no github deles: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane

É uma ótima ferramenta para o seu app whitelabel, você não precisará nem entrar mais no itunes connect para fazer as publicações. Você pode gerenciar eus apps totalmente por script.

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Pelo visto está é a melhor solução.